# How can I setup a user not to have acccess to publish pages but have contribute access - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, power-automate, publishing-page

I'm working on a project - using the site pages to publish news contents.

I want users to be able to create/edit pages but not to be able to publish them. Currently when a user creates a page, it get sent to an approver and ony when approved then it can be published,

But during my test I noticed users with contribute access can get and see the publish/unpublish in the context menu of each page.

Is it possible to remove this or even have a seperate permission level that can remove them from publishing?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you check that the "Require content approval for submitted items?" is turned on?

[image]

Generally, contributors are supposed to be able to Publish. Publishing really means that we are promoting a page from a minor version to a major version. There is no separate permission level that allows edits only for the minor versions.

However, if you have the content approval turned on, most users will not see "published" pages until these pages are approved. Also, instead of the "publish" button, the contributors should see the "Submit for approval" button:

[image]

Comment: As Denis Molodtsov said, there is no separate permission level to control publish feature.  The only workaround is using content approval feature.

Comment: Thanks Denis and Emily for your response. Since there is no perm level to control the publish feature. What happens if users with contribute click publish (Will they be prompted to submit for approval?)?
Please remember I don't want them to publish unless it has been approved  only by Approvers.
Does this make sense?

Comment: hi @naijacoder. It depends on whether the "Require content approval for submitted items" is turned on or off. What is the current value?